# Is there a R function to have 2 for loops

Tags: r

I have a problem. Initially I solved it for scenario 1. Scenario 1 is I have a dataframe df. I need to plot mean of the variables that are numeric

```
         df
         A     B   C  D   E  F
 1       asd   29  sf 36  sf 44
 2       fsd   24 gfd 56 gfd 34
 3       gs    46 asd 39 asd 37
 4       asd   50 gfg 26 gfg 23
 5       sf    43  fg 56  fg 37
 6       dfg   29  er 35  er 51
 7       sdfg  32  tr 27  tr 28
 8      fgdsgd 24  qw 31  qw 36
```

I have a code to plot the mean of variables that are numeric. The cod e is as shown below

```
 p2 <- list()
 cs <- names(Filter(is.numeric, df))
 for(i in cs)
 {
 p2[i] <- mean(df[,i])
 do.call(rbind,p2) %>% as.data.frame()
 }
 p2 <- as.data.frame(p2)
 p2 <- unlist(p2)
 p2 <- stack(p2)
 ggplot(data=p2,aes(x=ind,y=values))+geom_bar(stat = 
 "identity")+ylab("Mean")
```

But I need to have another loop. The above scenario is only mean. Now I also need median , Sd and many more. So i have called these function as a vector

```
 gh <- list()
 mea <- c("mean","median","sd")
 p2 <- list()
 cs <- names(Filter(is.numeric, df))
 for(i in cs)
 {
 for(j in mea)
 {
  p2[i] <- gh[[j]](df[i])
 do.call(rbind,p2) %>% as.data.frame()
 }
  }
 p2 <- as.data.frame(p2)
 p2 <- unlist(p2)
 p2 <- stack(p2)
 ggplot(data=p2,aes(x=ind,y=values))+geom_bar(stat = 
 "identity")+ylab("Mean")
```

Could you help me in building Scenario 2 that is the above one

So ideally it should plot mean, median and sd for all the variables that are numeric

Comment: have a look at `{dplyr}` package and the `summarise_if()` function. No need for loops

Comment: Thanks, Is it not possible in above loops?

Comment: for Summarise_if can you give me an example

Comment: it is faster without loops. `dplyr::summarise_if(df, is.numeric, list(mean,median,sd))`

Comment: Bernd perfect thanks. But is it not possible to have it seperately. After the last code of yours is executed, I get all in  a single data frame so it not possible to identity which is mean, median and sd

Comment: you can name the functions in the list to get nice names in the output and group_by to preserve groupings: `summarise_if(group_by(iris, Species), is.numeric, list(mean = mean,median = median, sd = sd))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it without loops using mtcars data set

```
apply(mtcars,2,function(x){
  if (is.numeric(x)){
    return(c("mean"=mean(x),"median"=median(x),"sd"=sd(x)))
  }
})
```

Comment: wouldn't it be safer to use is.numeric?